# Which tense is correct tense "This is/was the first stamp I (ever)"?

Tags: tense

Suppose I am holding a postage stamp in my hand, and then I talk to my friend about it.

(1) This **is** the first one I got for my collection.

(2) This **was** the first one I got for my collection.

(3) This **is** the first one I **ever** got for my collection.

(4) This **was** the first one I **ever** got for my collection.

Most of my friends think "is" in (1) is correct because I have it with me. They also say "was" in (4) is correct because of the word "ever". I agree with my friends.

What is your opinion?

Comment: In conversational English either (1) or (2) would be more common, and are roughly equivalent.  (3) and (4) are both also natural.  "Ever" adds emphasis that it is unique and the first.  Usually in English, brevity is preferred; "This was my first one ever" is also great and probably more common than (3) and (4).

Comment: Thank you for your help.